# regarding writing expression in derived column ssis

Tags: ssis-2012

I have a date column called `duedate`, i need to make a new column which is called `originaldate`.

`originaldate` column should have dates as - `duedate` column dates + `90` days.

So, i need to add 90 days to a date column.

Can you please hep me with the expression for adding 90 days to a date column.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for this is:

```
DATEADD(datepart, number, date)
```

So for you, it would be:

```
DATEADD("day", 90, duedate)
```